# Set of sql commands executed in single call considered as under transaction

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, transactions, transactionscope

In case I'm executing set of sql commands within single `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()` may I consider them under transaction by default or I should express transaction explicitly?

Would be `.NET` pattern `using(var scope = new TransactionScope) {...}` enough to make it transactional in case it isn't?

First part of command batch is declaration of table variable based on value of table being updated in second part.

```
DECLARE @tempTable TABLE (ID int,...)
INSERT INTO @tempTable (ID,...)
SELECT [ID],.. FROM [Table] WHERE ...
```

Second part is set of items which should be Updated or Inserted

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @tempTable WHERE ID=@id{0})
BEGIN
    UPDATE [Table]
    SET ... WHERE ...
END ELSE BEGIN
INSERT INTO [Table] ([ID], ...) VALUES (@id{0}, ...)
END
```

After they're concatenated I'm executing them by single call `SqlCommand.ExecuteQuery()`

Reason to do that batching is I'd like to minimize recurring transfers of parameters between SQL Server and my app since they're constants in scope of that batch.

Reason to ask is to prevent redundant code and understand whether it's possible that original data in `[Table]` (source of `@tempTable`) may change before last update/insert fragment of batch is finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executing SqlCommand won't begin any transaction.

You have two choices:

1. Use "BeginTransaction" from connection and passing transaction object to SqlCommand
2. Use TransactionScope, which uses DTC and allows you to manage transactions across multiple dbs

I would use the second.